# Use columns as facets in graph

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I have the CSV file sample below:

```
Time,Metric,JASK,ADI,IYW,NMNLK,AGWF,SDGYU,SDFWF,FFSDD,SDSF
2,HAUY,90,0,0,1,0.5,0.9,1,0,0.5
2,Z12IQ8,92.7605,0.758917751,0.40473,0.985702222,0.872985058,0.937119768,0.985702222,0.40473,0.872985058
2,9KAH,93.4582,0.804411769,0.45694,0.987653333,0.865519578,0.942423344,0.987653333,0.45694,0.865519578
2,P0IIDS,93.4284,0.757522078,0.50426,0.982064444,0.832763706,0.946890638,0.982064444,0.50426,0.832763654
2,SDGHG772,92.7298,0.740310258,0.42053,0.983605556,0.878374248,0.938563198,0.983605556,0.42053,0.878374248
2,RS,93.0309,0.816649558,0.39101,0.990231111,0.883847443,0.936039127,0.990231111,0.39101,0.883847443
2,IHSFH215,93.08156,0.775562283,0.435494,0.985851333,0.866698007,0.940207215,0.985851333,0.435494,0.866697996
4,HAUY,89.563,0,0,1,0.499887673,0.89563,1,0,0.499887673
4,Z12IQ8,92.6136,0.760067731,0.427134234,0.984285922,0.879761369,0.936484701,0.984285922,0.427134234,0.879761369
```

I want to graph it as a vertical bar in `ggplot2` where the column `Metric` is the x-axis, and its value the y-axis; I want each `Metric` grouped by the columns named `JASK`, ... `SDSF`:

```
require(ggplot2)

sample <- read.csv("path/to/data.csv")

ggplot(sample, aes(Metric, JASK)) + 
  labs(
    x="Metrics",
    y="Value (%)"
  ) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Metric), position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~    require(ggplot2)

sample <- read.csv("C:/Users/Troy/Dropbox/misc/data.csv")

ggplot(sample, aes(Metric, JASK)) + 
  labs(
    x="Metrics",
    y="Value (%)"
  ) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Metric), position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~Metric)
```

So far I used `c(JASK,ADI,IYW,NMNLK,AGWF,SDGYU,SDFWF,FFSDD,SDSF)` in the `facet_grid()` and ended up with an error:

```
Error in layout_base(data, cols, drop = drop) :
    At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

while using `facet_grid(~JASK+ADI+IYW+NMNLK+AGWF+SDGYU+SDFWF+FFSDD+SDSF)` ended in a disaster ([see here](http://imgur.com/ijiRLU5)).

How can I achieve a graph where:

- x-axis is `Metric` values
- y-axis is the raw values of `Metric`
- each are faceted/grouped by the variables `JASK`, `ADI`, `IYW`, `NMNLK`, `AGWF`, `SDGYU`, `SDFWF`, `FFSDD`, `SDSF`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key issue you're having is that ggplot expects data in long format.  You can get your data into long format by using `melt`:

```
library(reshape2)
df.mlt <- melt(df, id.vars=c("Time", "Metric"))
```

You should examine `df.mlt` to see what I mean by "long format".  With the data in long format plotting becomes trivial:

```
ggplot(df.mlt, aes(x=Metric, y=value, fill=as.factor(Time))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales="free_y") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

I don't know what you wanted to do with the `time` variable, so I just used it for the fill of the bars.  Note this is plotting only the data you excerpted.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can I change `value`s that are < 1 to be multiplied by 100 internally?

Comment: @PASTRY `df.mlt$value <- ifelse(df.mlt$value < 1, 100, 1) * df.mlt$value`, but be careful as this may cause some values in a facet to be multiplied by 100 while others not if some are above and others below one.  Also, I haven't tested this, but should be roughly right.

Comment: Hello it returns an error `Error in ifelse(df.mlt$value < 1, 100, 1) * df.mlt$value: non-numeric argument to binary operator`.

Comment: @PASTRY, it works for me.  Check the types of your columns with `str(df.mlt)`.  If they are not numeric (and should be), you can coerce to numeric with `df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)`